# How to reset and post custom data to Stormpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stormpath

I get JSON data from my client and want to save it to Stormpaths custom data using node.js with express.js:

I've got my basic post route:

```
app.post('/post', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res){
var data = req.body;
res.locals.user.customData.test = data;
res.locals.user.customData.save();
```

});

I basically want to overwrite the given data in customData.test and than save it, but right now it's adding the given data to customData.test.

How do i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to put the data properties directly onto the custom data object?  I'd suggest using an "extend" function that will copy the `data` properties onto the `customData` object.

For example using [Underscore extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
_.extend(req.locals.user.customData, data);
```

I also really like [xtend](https://github.com/Raynos/xtend)